# How to set OneDrive file picker (web apps) file types?

Tags: onedrive

I'm trying to integrate OneDrive file picker to a web application. I have managed to initialize the file picker and show the file dialog; however, I could not find anything in the available documentations and on the internet to show how to limit the dialog to show certain file types.

I wonder if anybody knows how to set the mime type or file type to be only documents and pdf files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now available! You can specify a list of file extensions that your app wants to allow the user to pick from, or use categories (like photos, folders) to specify a system-defined set of items that can be selected. More information is available here: https://dev.onedrive.com/sdk/js-v7/js-picker-open.htm#advanced-open-scenarios

Answer (score 1):

There's no supported way to limit the file picker to just show certain file types.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I asked for the feature to be added here:
http://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/suggestions/6933888-ability-to-set-mime-file-type-s-e-g-documents

Comment: There seems to be a progress on the request. It is being considered now. I hope they add this very required feature soon.